# How to Use Google BigQuery with the Google Places Library?

Tags: google-places-api, google-bigquery, google-places

I'm looking to use the BigQuery tool to create a table of businesses in the United States, and I want to draw the information from Google Places in order to get certain results from the XML feed to insert into my own database. I'm wondering if that would be possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be possible under the "Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service".

Check it at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms